# Test for independence confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question regarding the test for independence for matrices. If we have 3 vectors A1, A2, A3, then while creating the augmented matrix, do we write the 3 vectors horizontally (transpose) or do we write them vertically. I have seen both and I get confused which is the right way. If I am unable to express myself, I have attached examples. 
[image]

This is the first picture. X1 was the 4 by 1 vector (1, 2, -1, 0)^t which got written horizontally.

In the second picture here, 
[image]

the vectors are not written horizontally.

What is the reason behind choosing to write the transpose sometimes? Am I missing something? Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (popular) was of doing this.

1. Write the vectors $v_1,\ldots v_n$ as $\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n = 0$, break it up into a system of linear equations, then solve that system for $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$
2. Write your vectors horizontally as rows in a matrix, then row-reduce.

---

The first way used the definition of linear independence directly, while the second way provides a systematic way to find some linear dependence.

Your example on paper uses the second way, while it appears the textbook snipet is doing it the first way.

Comment: With the second method that you have written, I assume that we do not need to add a column for 0 vector like we do for the first method? Thanks for your response by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Because we want to transform columns in rows to perform row operations, which are more common in linear algebra. Although, there is no limitations to calculate using column operations also.